# Xamarin forms PopModalAsync doesn't trigger

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm building a Xamarin.Forms application with a facebook login using Xamarin.Auth.

Entry point (app.cs):

```
public App()
{
    MainPage = new WelcomePage();
}
```

WelcomePage:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Project
{
    public class WelcomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public WelcomePage()
        {
            var login = new Button { Text = "Login" };
            login.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());
            };

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("F0C640"),
                Padding = new Thickness(10, 40, 10, 10),
                Children = {
                    new Label { Text = "Please login" },
                    login
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

LoginPage:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Project
{
    public class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
    }
}
```

This is empty as I use Xamarin.Auth to authenticate with facebook so I created 2 different renderers on iOS and Android to display the facebook login page. After the login success I call an action which is located in my app.cs file:

```
public Action SuccessfulLoginAction
{
    get
    {
        return new Action(() => goToMainPage());
    }
}

public void goToMainPage()
{
    MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    //MainPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
    MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage());
}
```

At the end of the authentication the page is white but I believe it's a white page from Facebook after the authentication is done.

The SuccessfulLoginAction is well called so I go through the goToMainPage() function.

I put some breakpoints and PopModalAsync() doesn't do anything, same for PopToRootAsync() and PushAsync()...

The DetailPage is just a page with a Label. If I try to display it at the beginning of the process (app(){}) it display it well.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using PushModalAsync in your goToMainPage function?

And have you tried putting the await key word in front of the to async calls?

Comment: Hi @I_Khanage. I just tried MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DetailPage()); and to change the function to async + add await but it doesn't work neither...

Comment: Did you await both async calls in goToMainPage?

Comment: Yes I awaited both of them but no effect, I still have the same behaviour.

Comment: Try to put your `WelcomePage` into a navigation page to benefit from the navigation stack: `MainPage = new NavigationPage (new WelcomePage ());`

Comment: Hi @JoëlSalamin. I tried it so I have the top navigation bar, the modal login page is pushed but still the same problem I can't pop it... I tried with async and not async function.

Comment: @AntoineALEJANDRO Have a look here at [Hierarchical Navigation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/hierarchical/). From the popped page, a simple call to `await Navigation.PopAsync();` should remove it from the navigation stack.

Comment: Yes I had a look a it but I don't know why mine doesn't work...
I was wondering is it possible that `Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());` in my `WelcomePage` and `MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();` in my `app.cs` does not refer to the same Navigation?

Comment: @JoëlSalamin I tried it in a "normal" flow: WelcomePage displays DetailPage and DetailPage displays TestModalPage. With this format I can push and pop any of those pages with the functions Push/Pop (Modal) Async.
I don't know what's wrong with my code...

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue but could not. Could you upload a complete project sample in a new bug report? I'll take a look. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Forms

Comment: Hi @therealjohn, I actually solved the problem using an `Action`. I placed it in the `LoginPage` so it referred to the same `Navigation` and it poped the new `ModalPage`. 
In App.cs : `public static Action<string> SuccessfulLoginAction { get; set; }`.
In WelcomePage.cs: `App.SuccessfulLoginAction = async token =>{await Navigation.PopModalAsync();};`